# Accept call interfered by signal handler

Tags: c, sockets, signals

I'm using the accept call on a socket that should only accept connections with client processes. However, the signal handler implemented with sigaction for the signal SIGALRM is registered as a viable connection. I'm thinking I should check the connection with select or poll but I'm not sure if that's just complicating it. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Sorry about saying it was a connection. It just appeared to be a connection. My code had a while loop with a condition that ran as long as accept didn't evaluate to 0.

Update: So I just found my problem. The sigaction flag was the default. I changed it to SA_RESTART and accept works fine now. I think it has something to do with ignoring primitive I/O and returning EINTR but I'm not entirely sure about that. Anyone know?

Comment: How can a signal handler be a "viable connection"? That makes no sense whatsoever... connections are represented by file descriptors, `accept` returns a file descriptor, and a signal handler is not a file descriptor.

Comment: That's why I'm so confused. For some reason a connection is made when the signal handler captures a signal.

Comment: How do you know a connection is made?

Comment: Well looking at my code right now, I wouldn't say it's making a connection. It just appears to be so I'll just clarify that in the question. The accept call was a condition in a while loop like this: (client_sock = accept(stuff here))

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, system calls (including `accept`) can be interrupted by signals.

If a signal is received while a system call is in progress, the system call will be aborted and return the error `EINTR`. Even though this is an "error", it doesn't mean something went wrong, it just means you have to try the call again. The reasoning behind this design is rather complicated and out of scope of this question.

As you've found out, you can set the `sigaction` flag `SA_RESTART` to make this not happen for a particular signal. `accept` returns -1 if it encounters an error, so this would look something like:

```
while(1)
{
    int client_sock = accept(...);
    if(client_sock == -1)
    {
        if(errno == EINTR)
            continue; // try again
        ... normal error handling here ...
    }
    else
    {
        ... normal connection handling here ...
    }
}
```

A more robust solution would be to check for EINTR specifically - in case your program gets a signal that it wasn't prepared for, or in case some other code uses signals and doesn't set SA_RESTART. (That could be *your* code that you write 3 months later)